# TextInput disabled after closing keyboard

Tags: javascript, react-native

Using React Native TextInput, when tapping on the Back-Button (red 1 in the screenshot) while the keyboard is visible, the TextInput value can be edited at some later point. When tapping on the check/enter icon (red 2 in the screenshot) though, it's impossible to change the TextInput after the Keyboard disappears. When tapping on the input after that, the caret appears during the tap but then disappears and nothing happens.

[image]

This is my Component:

```
export class MyInput extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputValue: `${Date.now()}-document`,
        };

        this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this);
    }
    onFocus (text) {
        if (this.placeholderRemoved) {
            return text;
        }
        this.textInput.clear();
        this.placeholderRemoved = true;

        return '';
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView>
                <TextInput
                     value={this.state.inputValue}
                     onChangeText={(text) => {
                         this.setState({inputValue: text});
                     }}
                />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}
```

Tested with:

- Xiaomi Pocophone F1, Android 8.1
- Google Pixel 2 (Emulator), Android 7.1.1

[image]

How can I enable editing of the TextInput after closing the keyboard?

**Edit after @Sean Wangs request**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native';
import {MyInput} from './myInputViewComponent';

export default class myApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MyInput />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => myApp);
```

`"react": "16.7.0", "react-native": "0.57.6",`

Comment: What happens when you comment out your onFocus block? I feel like your return statements in there might be messing with something? Can you add a snippet of code of how the `MyInput` component is being used?

Comment: @SeanWang It's the same problem when copying and pasting the [TextInput example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.50/textinput#keyboardtype) from the docs into my index.js, so it should not be the onFocus block

Comment: Can you add your parent component code?

Comment: @SeanWang that's a higher order component containing most of the business logic for the application. That'd be beyond the scope of this question. Besides, this also happens when **only** using the [example code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.50/textinput#keyboardtype) from the docs.

Comment: Just need the one line where MyInput appears. The parent could very well be affecting the behavior of the component.

Comment: @SeanWang edited the question - verified the same behaviour with this as entry point

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting this issue on Google Pixel 2 (Emulator), Android 8.0.

Comment: @SeanWang could it be because of different react/native versions? I added my versions to the question

Comment: Possibly. It might be a new RN bug? I'll check later if you still don't have an answer.

Comment: @SeanWang it really appears to be some kind of focus problem. When I produce this error, and re-render the view I can select the input normally again

Comment: Are you missing something in your code? textInput is not available where does it come from what it is? And why don't you use placeholderText in combination with placeholderColor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and it is indeed an issue with RN version `0.57.6`. So your solution in this case would be to use RN version `0.57.7` or later and this issue should be resolved.

This is further confirmed as the release logs for `0.57.6` state that there was as issue introduced in `TextInput` which is fixed for `0.57.7` and on.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.57.6

Comment: Note: Latest version as of writing is RN `0.57.8` with React `16.6.3`

Answer (score 0):

use soft keyboard of either simulator or emulator.. You can check keyboard properties from hardware menu and search there.

Comment: Thank you, but this occurs on a real device too (Xiaomi Pocophone F1). I also don't want the users of the app to have the problem